# How to retrieve multiple values belonging to same "Id" in elasticsearch?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, bulk

I have indexed data based on a field say "A". There are about 18 values associated to same value of "A". Therefore, while indexing, elasticsearch has assigned same value of "A" to all the 18 records but has assigned specific version to each record.

Eg: Record 1 : A=1, _version=1, Record 2 : A=1, _version=2, Record 3 : A=1, _version=3 and so on.

The question is, how do i retrieve all these records belonging to one single value of "A" using Java? (BoolQuery, termsQuery, Scroll, multiMatchQuery are not being useful in this case. hence the doubt.)

Comment: It is not clear to me what you do with field A. Do you use A as the id? Can you show how you index the documents? The version you are referring to is used when you change the document. It seems to me you are updating the same document instead of creating new documents. If A has multiple values indeed, you usually get back an array of values for the source document. In short can you give some sample code explaining what you want to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

You can do an aggregation query to search for all documents and aggregate them using distinct aggregation on the field (A). This will give you all possible values of A. 
For query a document that matches on a specific field value you can do a term filter search by path.